# Cache Flushing issue in release build

Tags: c++, cpu

I am seeing a strange problem in this code:

```
namespace{
std::vector<int> my_vect;
}

thread1:
    sleep(5);
    my_vect.push_back(1);

main_thread:
    while(my_vect.empty());
    //do something
    return;
```

when built in debug, everything works as expected. When in release the while loop never exits...

When I changed to while loop from a busy wait to a:

```
while(my_vect.empty())
{
  sleep(1);
}
```

The release built started working again.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Why is my question down voted?

Comment: Without any synchronization your program contains a __data race__ which results in undefined behavior. Fix your code and the problem will go away.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, it did go away, but I don't understand why... What I was thinking is that even if the while loop observed an incorrect value for 1 iteration, I don't care. Next iteration, it'll be valid... Is that incorrect assumption? if so, then what's wrong with this logic?

Comment: @Kam, did you mean "Cache Flushing"?

Comment: YES that's what I meant :)

Comment: @Kam: That assumption isn't correct. A data race results in undefined behavior, period. You can't reliably reason about the code as it stands and the C++ standard doesn't define if or how it might execute. There is no guarantee what state the vector is in while `push_back()` is executing. You can't write concurrent code like this and just hope it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: Unsynchronized access to a shared variable is Undefined Behavior, and anything may happen. Your observed behavior isn't particularly unusual.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Kam: This is rather basic knowledge. Pick up any book on multi-threaded programming and it will tell you not to share variables _unless_

Comment: I know how synchronization work :) What I was thinking is that even if the while loop observed an incorrect value for 1 iteration, I don't care. Next iteration, it'll be valid... Is that incorrect assumption? if so, then what's wrong with this logic?

Comment: compiler basically optimizes it to `if (my_vect.empty()) {while(true);}`

Comment: @Erbureth Do you mind having your comment in an answer and please let me know how you figured that out? :)

Comment: @Kam: Your assumption is incorrect. Erbureth is right. The optimization is called hoisting, and moves unchanged variables (such as container size) out of the loop. The compiler knows it's unchanged because no other thread can change it because there's no synchronization.